# XAMPP wont start - Port is not 80

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, lamp

I recently installed XAMPP about a week or two ago, it's been working fine up 'till now. I had a small problem with port 80, so I changed it to 8080, 6794, 7777, etc. It's currently on 5555 and not working? I tried changing it to anything, but it didn't work? Any ideas?

Error:

```
21:16:40  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
21:16:40  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
21:16:40  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
21:16:40  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
21:16:40  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
21:16:40  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
21:16:40  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: _'Press the Logs button to view error logs'_

Answer (score 0):

Also change default port for https, if you have skype that port is already on use.

See ya.